# How can I make an Author Role publish content on the Strapi dashboard?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, blogs, strapi

I've been developing a blog for a few days, my idea is to give public access to the delivered news, but in the backend managed with Strapi, I have my role of superAdmin, Editor and Author. The Author can only add post, but when they do it, it is saved as draf, without the option of being able to publish.
I have 4 users with the Author Role in the Strapi admin panel. and what I want to know is if there is any possibility to give the Author Role the possibility to Publish the content.
(All the above mentioned is from the Roles of the Strapi Administration panel, **I am not talking about the Roles of Public and Authenticated**)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Strapi and I have been making some tests about the default roles of Strapi.

It appears that currently the default behaviour for the role `Author` in Strapi community edition is:

- The `Author` can only see content that it created
- The `Author` can NOT publish any content.

Therefor if you want to change that behaviour you need Strapi enterprise edition that gives you a granular access control.

If you go to the pricing page of Strapi (https://strapi.io/pricing-self-hosted) you can click on `Free Enterprise Edition trial` under the Silver plan to check if that actually fits your needs.